# Bison/Flex tutorial with C++, AST and re-entrant both lexer and parser

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer, abstract-syntax-tree

I am learning parsing, bison & lex. I am looking for a clear & complete tutorial/example that demonstrates all of:

1. C++ (not C) Abstract Syntax Tree.
2. Re-entrant lexer.
3. Re-entrant parser.
4. Reading from a string (vs. from file) would be nice as well.

I have found multiple examples and tutorials, but each typically meets only few of the above requirements. So far my best tutorial is from Chapter 3-2 in the Oreilly book by John Levine - it has AST; all C though, meets only Re_1 above. I welcome recommendations for nice examples / tutorials, real life open source projects. For example I saw MySql .yy file - looks well written, but too big/complex for beginner like me.

Comment: You mean coded in C++?  Or you want to parse C++?

Comment: I want my code that interacts with flex/bison to be C++. In particular the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). The mentioned example depends on c type-leniency. Plus I want to use STL, etc. As far as what I am trying to parse: a simple syntax similar to regular expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compiling flex and bison into cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619079/compiling-flex-and-bison-into-cpp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I combined several examples to get what I wanted. The top two examples were from John Levine's book on bison&flex (2nd edition), ISBN-10: 0596155972. The other one was from a phpcompiler website which unfortunaltly as of 2017-02-28 no longer exists. I am leaving the link here, in case the site is archived somewhere: www.phpcompiler.org/articles/reentrantparser.html

Thanks Adrien, here is an archived version (works as of 2017-03-02):

http://web.archive.org/web/20120520150851/http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/reentrantparser.html

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Comment: Indeed the phpcompiler.org webiste is gone, thanks for notifying me. I have edited my 2012 answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Radim, I just happened to need to write a (not so simple) compiler. It that OK for you to upload the example you assembled to somewhere like Github? People may find it useful, since exsiting examples really not easy to play with. Just wondering, thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, Jack, I will not be able to upload the code or help otherwise. We are talking 2012 (almost 5y ago) and the IP was owned by my employer, Fluential Inc/LLC (I do not know if they are still in business). Since then I have not worked on parsing and I do not remember much :(.

Comment: The URL has been uploaded to [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120520150851/http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/reentrantparser.html) several times. The closest snapshot of the website has been taken on 2017/05/20, is that the correct version you intended to show in your answer?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell this appears to be the same article.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to say that C++ grammar is too complex for Lex/Bison. The problem here is primarily in the grammar conflicts. It is not possible to write C++ grammar that does not have them. C++ standard explicitly states this and contains some guidelines on how to resolve them.

There is no generic solution for resolving grammar conflicts. In particular grammar conflicts resolution for C++ requires detailed knowledge about already defined identifiers. This means that you need to have bigger part of the C++ front end. Having just the grammar is not enough.

Nevertheless building an AST is possible. Look at a small sample program.

```
class HashEntry
{
private:

      int key;
      int value;

public:

      HashEntry(int key, int value)
      {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
      }

      int getKey() { return key; }

      int getValue() { return value; }
};

const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;

class HashMap
{
private:

      HashEntry **table;

public:

      HashMap()
      {
            table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];

            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  table[i] = NULL;
      }

      int get(int key)
      {
            int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);

            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                  hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

            if (table[hash] == NULL)
                  return -1;
            else
                  return table[hash]->getValue();
      }

      void put(int key, int value)
      {
            int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);

            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                  hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

            if (table[hash] != NULL)
                  delete table[hash];

            table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
      }     

      ~HashMap()
      {
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  if (table[i] != NULL)
                        delete table[i];

            delete[] table;
      }
};
```

And this is an AST for this program:
[image]

This tree is severely zoomed out. Yellow circles at the leafs (very small) are terminal symbols, green circles in the middle are non terminals. Pink circle in the center is the TranslationUnit. This tree has 2009 nodes.

Comment: Hi Kirill, as I indicated in another comment, I am not trying to parse c++, I just want to use bison/flex in a c++ project. I have a solution now, I am going to try to close this question.