# compiling flex and bison into cpp

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

Usually, when we compile .l and .y files, we get .tab.h,.tab.c and .yy.c files. However, I need to use these in a C++ environment with types that are only available in C++. How do you modify your code so as to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can compile the generated files using your trustworthy C++ compiler, so you don't have to rewrite the whole thing.

If you want to go "full c++", keep reading.

For **Flex**, you need to specifiy **%option c++** in the file.
You can also change the generated C++ lexer name using **--yyclass=NAME** command line argument.

For **Bison**, just follow these instructions (excerpt taken from Bison manual)

```
if you need to put  C++  code  in  the
input  file, you can end his name by a C++-like extension (.ypp or .y++), then bison will follow your exten-
sion to name the output file (.cpp or .c++).  For instance, a grammar description file named parse.yxx would
produce the generated parser in a file named parse.tab.cxx, instead of yacc y.tab.c or old Bison version's
parse.tab.c.
```

P.S: Be aware that **c++** and **reentrant** options are mutually exclusive in Flex.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify output filenames with command-line flags, so you don't need to modify your code at all to produce `.cc` files, which will save you some complication with makefiles or equivalent.

As long as your actions and other code blocks are valid C++ code and you don't include non-POD types in the semantic union directly (pointers are fine; smart pointers, not), you shouldn't need to modify anything.

You could also use the C++ templates in flex and bison, but I've generally found it easier to stick with the C templates, which will compile just fine with C++.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this tutorial for Flex/Bison in C++: http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/FlexBisonC++

The code repository is up to date and compatible with the latest C++ compilers: 
https://github.com/jonathan-beard/simple_wc_example

Specifically I'd take a look at the examples

```
void 
MC::MC_Driver::add_word( const std::string &word )
{
   words++; 
   chars += word.length();
   for(const char &c : word ){
      if( islower( c ) )
      { 
         lowercase++; 
      }
      else if ( isupper( c ) ) 
      { 
         uppercase++; 
      }
   }
}
```

where a string (C++ type) is passed from the parser (.yy file) here:

```
item
  : UPPER   { driver.add_upper(); }
  | LOWER   { driver.add_lower(); }
  | WORD    { driver.add_word( $1 ); }
  | NEWLINE { driver.add_newline(); }
  | CHAR    { driver.add_char(); }
  ;
```

Basically as long as the C++ binary knows how to handle the object then everything will work nicely. To figure out why this works, I'd definitely check out the GitHub repository and play with the code a bit.

Hope this helps. -J