# Porting C bison parser to C++

Tags: c++, c, bison

I use reentrant FLEX C based scanner and reentrant bison C based parser. It works fine.

I wish to keep reentrant C based FLEX scanner and to get reentrant bison C++ based parser.

Why? When the input is too complex (too long if-else-if chain), then limitation about bison's stack size is problem. Also, I dislike undocumented solutions and solutions where authors says that something will be changed and so on. This is why I wish to keep C based FLEX scanner.

Also, I need to use specific prefixes or suffixes or namespaces to use multiple reentrant FLEX C based scanners and reentrant bison C++ based parsers.

Thanx

Comment: Why do you think the Bison stack size would change for a C++ implementation of Bison? Otherwise, nothing stops you from using C++ code in the Bison actions. And you might want to search for "Bison++".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Bison's C++ template implements the parser stack using a `std::vector`, leaving it to that standard library datatype to implement any size limit. I don't believe most `std::vector` implementations do anything other than respond to allocation failures (if these occur; as we all know, platforms with optimistic memory allocation generally don't report allocation failure in a useful fashion).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compiling flex and bison into cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619079/compiling-flex-and-bison-into-cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get your hands on writing parsers in C++ using Flex & Bison, here comes the answer.

[This article](http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/FlexBisonC++) provides answer to your question. The author is using Flex and Bison in C++ freely, in OO manner. In case of Flex, you can make use of `%{ ... %}` code blocks. On the other hand, in case of Bison, that's how really, really generic parser would look in C++ according to author:

```c
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require  "3.0"
%debug 
%defines 
%define api.namespace {MC}
%define parser_class_name {MC_Parser}

%code requires{
   namespace MC {
      class MC_Driver;
      class MC_Scanner;
   }

// The following definitions is missing when %locations isn't used
# ifndef YY_NULLPTR
#  if defined __cplusplus && 201103L <= __cplusplus
#   define YY_NULLPTR nullptr
#  else
#   define YY_NULLPTR 0
#  endif
# endif

}

%parse-param { MC_Scanner  &scanner  }
%parse-param { MC_Driver  &driver  }

%code{
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <fstream>

   /* include for all driver functions */
   #include "mc_driver.hpp"

#undef yylex
#define yylex scanner.yylex
}

%define api.value.type variant
%define parse.assert

%token               END    0     "end of file"
%token               UPPER
%token               LOWER
%token <std::string> WORD
%token               NEWLINE
%token               CHAR

%locations

%%

list_option : END | list END;

list
  : item
  | list item
  ;

item
  : UPPER   { driver.add_upper(); }
  | LOWER   { driver.add_lower(); }
  | WORD    { driver.add_word( $1 ); }
  | NEWLINE { driver.add_newline(); }
  | CHAR    { driver.add_char(); }
  ;

%%


void 
MC::MC_Parser::error( const location_type &l, const std::string &err_message )
{
   std::cerr << "Error: " << err_message << " at " << l << "\n";
}
```

... and the driver code:

```c
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

#include "mc_driver.hpp"

MC::MC_Driver::~MC_Driver()
{
   delete(scanner);
   scanner = nullptr;
   delete(parser);
   parser = nullptr;
}

void 
MC::MC_Driver::parse( const char * const filename )
{
   /**
    * Remember, if you want to have checks in release mode
    * then this needs to be an if statement 
    */
   assert( filename != nullptr );
   std::ifstream in_file( filename );
   if( ! in_file.good() )
   {
       exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }
   parse_helper( in_file );
   return;
}

void
MC::MC_Driver::parse( std::istream &stream )
{
   if( ! stream.good()  && stream.eof() )
   {
       return;
   }
   //else
   parse_helper( stream ); 
   return;
}


void 
MC::MC_Driver::parse_helper( std::istream &stream )
{

   delete(scanner);
   try
   {
      scanner = new MC::MC_Scanner( &stream );
   }
   catch( std::bad_alloc &ba )
   {
      std::cerr << "Failed to allocate scanner: (" <<
         ba.what() << "), exiting!!\n";
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }

   delete(parser); 
   try
   {
      parser = new MC::MC_Parser( (*scanner) /* scanner */, 
                                  (*this) /* driver */ );
   }
   catch( std::bad_alloc &ba )
   {
      std::cerr << "Failed to allocate parser: (" << 
         ba.what() << "), exiting!!\n";
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }
   const int accept( 0 );
   if( parser->parse() != accept )
   {
      std::cerr << "Parse failed!!\n";
   }
   return;
}

void 
MC::MC_Driver::add_upper()
{ 
   uppercase++; 
   chars++; 
   words++; 
}

void 
MC::MC_Driver::add_lower()
{ 
   lowercase++; 
   chars++; 
   words++; 
}

void 
MC::MC_Driver::add_word( const std::string &word )
{
   words++; 
   chars += word.length();
   for(const char &c : word ){
      if( islower( c ) )
      { 
         lowercase++; 
      }
      else if ( isupper( c ) ) 
      { 
         uppercase++; 
      }
   }
}

void 
MC::MC_Driver::add_newline()
{ 
   lines++; 
   chars++; 
}

void 
MC::MC_Driver::add_char()
{ 
   chars++; 
}


std::ostream& 
MC::MC_Driver::print( std::ostream &stream )
{
   /** NOTE: Colors are defined as class variables w/in MC_Driver **/
   stream << red  << "Results: " << norm << "\n";
   stream << blue << "Uppercase: " << norm << uppercase << "\n";
   stream << blue << "Lowercase: " << norm << lowercase << "\n";
   stream << blue << "Lines: " << norm << lines << "\n";
   stream << blue << "Words: " << norm << words << "\n";
   stream << blue << "Characters: " << norm << chars << "\n";
   return(stream);
}
```

Much better explaination (compared to just comments above) of this code can be found on authors website linked two paragraphs above. I really advice you to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're under no obligation to use flex's C++ template in a C++ program. The C code generated by flex should compile and execute correctly in C++. (At least, I haven't seen a problem.) As indicated in the flex documentation, any C++ incompatibility in the generated C code will be treated as a bug and should be reported as such.

Having said that, if your only concern with bison's C template is the limitation on parser stack size, you can easily increase the limit by defining `YYMAXDEPTH`. In particular, you can essentially avoid any limit by using:

```
#define YYMAXDEPTH (YYSTACK_ALLOC_MAXIMUM / YYSTACK_BYTES (1))
```

(That formula was derived from a comment in the skeleton `data/yacc.c`:

```
/* YYMAXDEPTH -- maximum size the stacks can grow to (effective only
   if the built-in stack extension method is used).

   Do not make this value too large; the results are undefined if
   YYSTACK_ALLOC_MAXIMUM < YYSTACK_BYTES (YYMAXDEPTH)
   evaluated with infinite-precision integer arithmetic.  */
```

I don't know if that comment really constitutes formal documentation, but it seems to be addressed to people who might consider changing the value of `YYMAXDEPTH` so I'm assuming that it's OK to rely on it. :-) ) On the other hand, you might well consider imposing some smaller limit, since just leaving it to `malloc()` to report allocation failure -- which is the result of the above `#define` -- is notoriously unreliable on platforms which use optimistic memory allocation.

The issue with optimistic memory allocation is not avoided by switching to C++, since bison's C++ template relies on `std::vector` to report memory allocation failure, and none of the standard library implementations I know of attempt to predict future unavailability of optimistic allocated memory.